# List container images in Kubernetes cluster with SIZE (like docker image ls)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In the Kubernetes documentation [List All Container Images Running in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-all-container-images-in-all-namespaces) we can list all containers by:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}" |\
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |\
sort |\
uniq -c
```

Here is an example of output:

```
  1 cdkbot/addon-resizer-amd64:1.8.1
  1 cdkbot/hostpath-provisioner-amd64:1.0.0
  1 cdkbot/registry-amd64:2.6
  1 coredns/coredns:1.6.6
  1 docker.io/cdkbot/addon-resizer-amd64:1.8.1
  1 docker.io/cdkbot/hostpath-provisioner-amd64:1.0.0
  1 docker.io/cdkbot/registry-amd64:2.6
  1 docker.io/coredns/coredns:1.6.6
  1 docker.io/grafana/grafana:6.4.3
  2 docker.io/istio/citadel:1.5.1
  2 docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-details-v1:1.15.0
  2 docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-productpage-v1:1.15.0
  2 docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-ratings-v1:1.15.0
  2 docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1:1.15.0
  2 docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v2:1.15.0
  2 docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v3:1.15.0
  2 docker.io/istio/galley:1.5.1
  4 docker.io/istio/kubectl:1.5.1
  4 docker.io/istio/mixer:1.5.1
  2 docker.io/istio/pilot:1.5.1
 34 docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.5.1
  2 docker.io/istio/sidecar_injector:1.5.1
  2 docker.io/jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.16
  1 docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0
  1 docker.io/kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.4
  2 docker.io/library/nginx:latest
  2 docker.io/prom/prometheus:v2.12.0
  1 docker.io/radial/busyboxplus:curl
  1 grafana/grafana:6.4.3
  2 k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.2.1
  1 kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0
  1 kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.4
  2 nginx
  2 quay.io/kiali/kiali:v1.9
  1 radial/busyboxplus:curl
```

Unfortunately the size of the docker image is missing. Is there a way to get the container image size? Pretty much like `docker image ls`. Copy of the output from this [example](http://www.askdevops.org/63/docker-list-all-images-local-docker-image-ls-example) for convenience:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.io/ubuntu            latest              3556258649b2        7 days ago          64.2 MB
docker.io/alpine            latest              b7b28af77ffe        2 weeks ago         5.58 MB
docker.io/centos            latest              9f38484d220f        4 months ago        202 MB
docker.io/hello-world       latest              fce289e99eb9        7 months ago        1.84 kB
```

Comment: Hi which ressources do you try to get ? CPU ? Memory only ? both ?

Comment: @yAzou List the container images and the size of each image.

Comment: i previously posted an answer to your question but i realized that it will gives you the size in memory of pods....not of the image hosted by each pods...even if i think that the difference between them is not so important...I delete my answer after noticed that it will not give you the exact answer to your question....let me know if you would like me to show it anyway

Comment: @yAzou of course, I am more than interested. Even if this doesn't answer exactly to the question. This help me to learn new tricks. Thanks.

Comment: I undelete it....please let me know if it helps somehow

Answer (score 22):

If you have the correct permissions, get the nodes not the pods.

```
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].status.images[] | .names[1], .sizeBytes'
```

Comment: This answer looks like a good start! Consider elaborating on why _nodes_ should be used instead of _pods_. Another good practice for giving command line solutions is to explain the different components of the command you have suggested and what options are being used.

Comment: I used this as the base for a couple of months just to realize today that `kubectl get nodes -o json` does not list all images in use... there are some pods, running long this same node that do not appear. Any explanation would be appreciated

Comment: replacing `.sizeBytes` with `(.sizeBytes | tonumber/1024/1024)` to convert it to MB (approximately) and can be more human readable.

Answer (score 1):

On my k8s system kubectl describe pod ABC doesn't show the image size, but you can create a script that:

1. gets the name of the image (I assuming you have one container in the pod, otherwise the script will be slightly more complicated depending on what you want to print actually)
2. runs docker image ls on the same machine. This assumes that you actually have that docker image on the machine you're running this command.
3. You slight format the output of that command to "catch" the image size

All-in-all it looks like this:

```
docker image ls `kubectl get pod YOUR_POD_NAME_GOES_HERE  -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[0].image}'` --format='{{println .Size}}'
```

Comment: The pods I use have 1, 2, 3 containers inside. With 2, 3 the majority of cases. The type of app I use have sidecar containers injected when the app is deployed.

Comment: Well, in this case, you'll have to slightly modify the script and use `-o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[1].image}'` or ('2' or '3' depending on what you want).

Comment: `kubectl get pod my-nginx-5dc4865748-8cm8m -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[0].image}'` does return `nginx` as the docker image name. However when I wrap `docker image ls` around it as you suggest, the result is empty. FYI my K8S is microk8s.

Comment: Nginx is probably not available in the node that you're running the command in. Try to see on which nodes the nginx pod actually deployed...

Comment: I have verified that the image exists by running `kubectl get pod my-nginx-5dc4865748-8cm8m -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[0].image}'`. This is a single node setup (microk8s). All commands are run on that single node (Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: And if you run `docker images | grep nginx` do you see that image? I’m not familiar with microk8s, sorry...

Comment: No need to `grep`, I would have been happy with the output of `docker images`. It looks like docker doesn't see any image.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly run below two commands for listing all downloaded and working images in kubernetes pods with size.

```
 kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' | sort -u | while read -r image; do size=$(docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} {{.Size}}' | grep "$image" | awk '{print $2}'); size_in_mb=$(echo "$size" | awk '{gsub(/[A-Za-z]/, "", $0); print $0 / 1024 / 1024}'); echo "$image ($size_in_mb MB)"; done
```

Comment: Hey, that's very cool and I will reuse parts of it, thanks! But, ultimately, your command invokes the `docker` CLI which will query only the images that are available (pulled) on a current Kubernetes node. Unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes doesn't provide image size information in its outputs. Even though we able to get a list of images running in a cluster, it is not a straight forward process to get the size of an image in a multi-node cluster. But in such cases where we run a single node cluster, we could achieve this by running a docker or DinD (Docker in Docker) container in Kubernetes cluster. Still, it is a good approach for testing purposes only. I have nothing to say about running this on critical environments. It depends.

Spin up a pod by mounting host's `/var/lib/docker.sock` file inside and exec as shown below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: dind
  name: dind
spec:
  containers:
  - image: docker:dind
    name: dind
    command: ["cat"]
    tty: true
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      name: docker
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: docker
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
      type: File
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

---

```
$ kubectl exec -i dind -n dev sh -- docker images nginx 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx               latest              4571e56e27f0        11 hours ago        132MB

$kubectl exec -i dind -n dev sh -- docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx                                                            latest              4571e56e27f0        21 hours ago        132MB
```

Comment: Thanks this looks exciting. I had to remove `readOnly: true` (microk8s 1.18.3 reports error "ValidationError(Pod.spec.volumes[0].hostPath): unknown field "readOnly" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.HostPathVolumeSource". After that, exec `docker images ls` in that "dind" pod only returns the header line. No docker image listed.

Comment: @Polymerase I have updated the answer. The param `readOnly: true` should come under `volumeMounts` and the command `docker image ls` will list the images.

Comment: deleted + recreated the "dind" pod. Ran `kubectl exec -i dind sh -- docker image ls` (NOTE `-n dev` removed). Same issue, only header line. No docker images were found, and I have plenty of containers in various pods. What is your K8S environment? Mine is MicroK8S on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Polymerase I am running K8s v1.18.3 on Minikube.

Comment: "K8s v1.18.3 on Minikube" on which OS?

Comment: @Polymerase Mac OS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

Check if which container runtime is used in the Kubernetes platform. For example if 'microk8s', here is the command:

```
sudo microk8s ctr image ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar thing (but primarily list images and what pods are using them). So I created kubectl plugin which lists images (and their sizes as well) and also pods/containers that use them.
This is the link - https://github.com/pete911/kubectl-image

```
kubectl image list -A

registry: registry.k8s.io
  coredns/coredns
    Tag/ID: v1.9.3      Size: 13.42MB
    ID:     sha256:b19406328e70dd2f6a36d6dbe4e867b0684ced2fdeb2f02ecb54ead39ec0bac0
            [namespace] kube-system [container] coredns [pod] coredns-565d847f94-kfs8m [pod-phase] Running
            [namespace] kube-system [container] coredns [pod] coredns-565d847f94-r9wvh [pod-phase] Running
...
```